# properly enforce pre-defined loop time

Tags: python, python-2.7, infinite-loop, frequency

I am trying to measure a voltage through an acquisition card at a precise frequency, and I don't find effective tools to enforce my loop to run at said frequency.

For now I have something like this:

```
import time

def get_data(frequency):
    last_t=time.time()
    while True:
       while (time.time()-last_t)<(1./frequency): # waiting loop
           time.sleep(1./(100*frequency)) # wait for 1/100 of the desired loop time
       last_t=time.time()
       data=sensor.acquire()
       # do stuff with the data
```

1/ This is not very precise, as it only enforce that frequency will not be higher than wanted frequency (but can be much lower).

2/ This is expensive in CPU time, because the waiting loop is very fast, but I don't know how to improve it.

Any idea for improving one (or both) of these issues will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have those very small sleeps? Just wait for the period without making tons of small sleeps. Which hardware is your acquisition card? Try to get it included in a `select` loop. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475434/a-way-to-almost-correctly-trigger-a-function-periodically/32476259#32476259

Comment: I don't know precisely how much time I will have to wait at each loop, because the data treatment time is not constant. I made this small sleeps so I can limit the usage of CPU without oversleeping too much (but I know it is not ideal). My acquisition card is an usb-dux sigma, capable of 8kHz acquisition

Comment: I just took a look at your `select` solution, but it seems too "slow" for my application. I know that I'm in the limits of what it is possible to do on a computer with this kind of frequency, but I just wonder if someone has a way of improving it.

Comment: 8KHz is not a limit at all... Can't you do buffering to decouple data acquisition from data treatment ? e.g do data acquisition in a thread, and fill a queue with data, having data processing taking data from the queue

Comment: By the way why do you think it seems too slow with the `select` ? Could you give it a try or is it just an assumption?

Comment: for `select`, based on the example in the post you linked, they have +-5ms on a 5second loop, so I assume it's not good for a 8kHz loop. The problem I have is if I want to chose the frequency and acquire data at, say 2kHz, how to ensure my loop won't be faster nor slower?

Comment: It is not my domain, by far, but maybe it is worth talking to the guys at pycrypto; they are implementing crypto algorithms that are required to perform in identical time to avoid leaking information. They might have a lead for you.

Comment: I will try with pycrypto, thank you. I tested `select` on ipython with a simple `%timeit` and results are similar to `time.sleep`